# Xcode Server Bot won't connect to Gitlab server (Fails to integrate)

Tags: ios, xcode, git, ssh, xcode-server

I'm trying to integrate a simple Xcode Bot with my Xcode server.

> *I'm using OS X Server 5 Beta 3 and Xcode 7 Beta 5*

I create a bot and everything goes great. I use an existing ssh key for connecting to this git repository on gitlab and that works fine everywhere else and even Xcode (in accounts preferences) seems to not have a problem with the repo.

But when I go to integrate the bot, it fails to check out the source with:

> **Failed to authenticate SSH session: Callback returned error (-1)**

I've tried changing this to use my actual gitlab credentials instead of the ssh key and I get the same error. It doesn't seem to matter what I use for the bot, it fails to sign in. Yet all of those credentials work on gitlab using git and Xcode itself just fine.

Anyone else run into this? And/or are there any better logs somewhere of what's going on?

Not much in the verbosity in the xcodebuild logs on the server either:

> 2015-08-10 09:42:28.303 xcsbuildd[14203:84978] XCSIntegrationExecutor.m:229 [XCSIntegrationExecutor integrationStep:didFinishWithError:result:] [BuildService, Error] XCSCheckoutIntegrationStep finished integration with an error: Error Domain=XCSBuildServiceDomain Code=-1 "Could not checkout sources because the source control information is in an invalid format. UserInfo=0x7fb8ece65810 {NSLocalizedDescription=Could not checkout sources because the source control information is in an invalid format., XCSErrorFixItType=scm-failure}

Not sure what it means by invalid format?:

> Could not checkout sources because the source control information is
>   in an invalid format

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @stevekohls no not yet. Hoping to jump back on this again soon though with all the latest updates.